# UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight is not working in ios 9.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have use this below code:

```
if(([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] respondsToSelector:@selector(isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:)]) && [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){9, 0, 0}]){                  
[[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];     }
```

It's working on iOS9 but doesn't in iOS9.2.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the keyboard type to `[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable]`. So , it is set english characters only.After which the above `UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight` should work.